1:1 pairs of elements from two lists within a for loop in R
I have two lists, list1 and list2, and I need to loop through a series of 1:1 pair within a for loop. For examples,
list1 <- c('1', '2', '3')
list2 <- c('a', 'b', 'c')

What I want is to use 'a' as a prefix for a data frame name and variable names if list1=='1', then 'b' if list1=='2', and 'c' if list1=='3'. Below codes will go through all combinations, like 1-a, 1-b, 1-c, 2-a, 2-b, 2-c, 3-a, 3-b, and 3-c. But I only need 1-a, 2-b, and 3-c pairs.
I am relatively new to R, so I would appreciate your advice!
for (x in list1) {
   for (y in list2) {
      past(y, "_df", sep="") <- df[[x]] # not sure if this would work or not          
   }
}


After bringing the list entries into the desired order, try mapply(\(x, y) paste0(x, "-", y), list1, list2)

df is a list of 3 data.frames and you want to assign those frames to objects named a_df, b_df, c_df ?

@margusl, yes, that's correct.

It's not really something you should normally aim for, but you could try names(df) <- paste0(list2, "_df"); list2env(df, envir = environment()) .
